# Shell Script Commands Work Fine in Terminal But Not Via AppleScript

Tags: terminal, applescript, command-line

I have two commands that I need to run through the Terminal. They are
`cd /Users/[my name]/Desktop` and `curl 'www.google.com'>google.txt`.
When running these directly in Terminal they work just fine. However, when running this in AppleScript:

```
do shell script "cd /Users/Peter1/Desktop"
do shell script "curl 'www.google.com'>google.txt"
```

It produced the error:

```
sh: google.txt: Permission denied
```

Why is this happening? What can I do to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script above is running two different scripts. One is changing the working directory to your user desktop folder (`~/Desktop`). The other script is downloading `www.google.com` and putting it in a document in your root directory (`/`), which doesn't have permissions to do so.

You can fix this by reduce it to one statement of `do shell script` like such:

```
do shell script "curl www.google.com > ~/Desktop/google.txt"
```

In short, the script first downloads the contents of the website `www.google.com` and then creates a new file at the specified directory. You may also notice the `~` character, which is equivalent to `/Users/username/`.

Comment: Ah, OK, thanks. I was thinking that the first command turns the working directory to the desktop, and the second saves a file there (on the desktop)